# CSS full screen div with text in the middle

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a css class defined so I can make a div to use all the browser's viewport, the rule is the following:

```
.fullscreenDiv {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Now I want the text inside the div to be in the exact center of the screen so, vertical align center and horizontal align middle, but I can't seem to find the proper way to do so.

It only needs to work on webkit based browsers.

I already tried to add a P element inside with `display` set to `table-cell` (a common way of centering text) without luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ```text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    width: 100%;``` - This should work better than the accepted answer - Add the styles to your bit of text

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The standard approach is to give the centered element fixed dimensions, and place it absolutely:

```
<div class='fullscreenDiv'>
    <div class="center">Hello World</div>
</div>​

.center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; /* margin is -0.5 * dimension */
    margin-top: -25px; 
}​
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/wzSmc/)

Comment: I'm trying with this, but if I wanted to center the text in the middle of the "center" div as well?

Comment: @JuanAlbertoLópezCavallotti You would just be reproducing the problem. Adding `text-align: center` to the `center` class would get you halfway there. If its just 1 line of text, you can add `line-height: 50px`, or whatever the height of the centered container is. That will vertically center it as well.

Comment: Not sure if the extra element was needed but here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/wzSmc/1/

Comment: @JuanAlbertoLópezCavallotti updated DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/wzSmc/2/

Comment: Thanks @paislee that solved my problem it is looking the right way and that's what counts!

Comment: Also thank you @FelipeAlsacreations I used part of your solution too. The inner p was not necessary!

Answer (score 87):

The accepted answer works, but if:

- you don't know the content's dimensions
- the content is dynamic
- you want to be future proof

use this:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed; /* or absolute */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

More information about centering content in this excellent [CSS-Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/).

---

Also, if you don't need to support old browsers: a flex-box makes this a piece of cake:

```
.center{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Another great guide about flexboxs from CSS Tricks; http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Great answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no pure CSS solution to this classical problem.

If you want to achieve this, you have two solutions:

- Using a table (ugly, non semantic, but the only way to vertically align things that are not a single line of text)
- Listening to window.resize and absolute positionning

***EDIT***: when I say that there is no solution, I take as an hypothesis that you don't know in advance the size of the block to center. If you know it, paislee's solution is very good

Answer (score 1):

`text-align: center` will center it horizontally as for vertically put it in a span and give it a css of `margin:auto 0;` (you will probably also have to give the span a `display: block` property)